# A bash script that will start when the EC2 instance is turned on

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, amazon-ec2

I have a EC2 instance, and I would like to write a script (never done them before) so that every time I start my E2 instance in the AWS console, the following files are run automatically.

Lets say I have a file called `example.js` which contains this:

```
var test(){
console.log('hello world');
}
test()
```

And then I have a similar file called `example2.js`

Everytime I run my EC2 instance, I need to ssh into it and do `node example.js` and `node example2.js` in order to run the functions.

However, I would like to write a startup script so that when the EC2 instance state is turned to running (i.e. online), I would like the command `node example.js` and `node example2.js` executed by themselves.

Is this possible? If yes, where do I put this script?

I have a Centos image running on my EC2 instance, and the EC2 instance is turned off at night, and turned back on in the morning - hence the script will simplify things!

I read this link, however cannot quite figure it out in my case: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What about `/etc/rc.local`?

Comment: What about etc/rc.local?

Comment: Well, it's a script that automatically runs every time the instance boots up.

Answer (score 1):

use pm2. It's an excellent solution for managing node processes. Also can start the processes when you boot the machine.

ref: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/

here is another good tutorials: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/pm2-restart-processes-after-system-reboot

Comment: I've had issues with PM2 on reboot and EC2 in the past, I would recommend your solutions for another hosting service though :)

Answer (score 1):

Specific to EC2, you can use the 'User Data' option, available when you create your instance. It takes a script as input that will be executed at launch.

Here's how it looks like :

[image]

To add user data to your instance, wait until the night so you don't disrupt yor apps, then right click on it and do "Create Image".

Once the image is created, you can use it to spawn a "new" instance, with user data, and delete the old one without losing anything. Don't forget to reassign the elastic IP of the old instance :)

[More information/documentation on aws.amazon.com](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)

Comment: What if the instance is already created? Or the script needs to be changed later on in the time?

Comment: you can take an image of your instance and recreate it without losing any data, and with the user data :)